How to do Depparser work using custom universal dependecy model?
I don't want to write down rules of extraction triples of relations as we do using Spacy, like example below (The reason is that there is many and i don't have proficiency to write all of them):
            # (...)
            # Extrair Relações com Base em Substantivos e Preposições
            if token.dep_ == "prep":
                subject = [w for w in token.head.lefts if w.dep_ == "nsubj"]
                obj = [w for w in token.rights if w.dep_ == "pobj"]
                if subject and obj:
                    relations.append((subject[0].text, token.text, obj[0].text))

            # Extrair Relações com Base em Nouns e Seus Predicativos
            if token.dep_ == "attr":
                subject = [w for w in token.head.lefts if w.dep_ == "nsubj"]
                if subject:
                    relations.append((subject[0].text, token.head.lemma_, token.text))
            # (...)

Because this, i want use CoreNPL + Universal Dependencies to extract the relations. I/m using pt_bosque_models. Bellow some details:

Link of UD model: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanfordnlp_models/0.2.0/pt_bosque_models.zip
Version of UD: 2.14
Version of corenlp: 4.5.7

To wake up the server i'm using this command:
 java  -cp "stanford-corenlp-4.5.7.jar"  edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -serverProperties StanfordCoreNLP-portuguese.properties -port 9000 -timeout 15000 

My StanfordCoreNLP-portuguese.properties file content is:
annotators = tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse
#tokenize.language = pt
ssplit.eolonly = true
# Modelo de dependência
depparse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/UD_Portuguese-Bosque.gz

The follow files are in UD_Portuguese-Bosque.gz:
LICENSE.txt
pt_bosque-ud-dev.conllu
pt_bosque-ud-dev.txt
pt_bosque-ud-test.conllu
pt_bosque-ud-test.txt
pt_bosque-ud-train.conllu
pt_bosque-ud-train.txt
README.md
stats.xml

This is my python example of request file:
import requests

# URL do servidor Stanford CoreNLP
url = 'http://[::1]:9000'

# Sentença de exemplo
sentence = "Qual é a opinião de Carl Sagan sobre a possibilidade de formas de vida baseadas em elementos diferentes do carbono e água?"

# Parâmetros para a requisição
params = {
    'annotators': 'depparse,ner',
}

#tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse,
# Dados para a requisição
data = {
    'data': sentence
}
# Requisição ao servidor CoreNLP
response = requests.post(url, params=params, data=data)

# Verificar se a requisição foi bem sucedida
print(response)
if response.status_code == 200:
    result = response.json()
    for sentence in result['sentences']:
        for triple in sentence['openie']:
            print("Relação extraída:", triple['subject'], triple['relation'], triple['object'])
else:
    print("Erro ao fazer requisição ao servidor Stanford CoreNLP.")

The Problem:
If "depparse" is present on params i get the error:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "MDA4MTs2NmE2ZTExZDtDaHJvbWU7"
  java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
  java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:668)
  java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:786)
  edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser.loadModelFile(DependencyParser.java:539)
  edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParserCache$DependencyParserSpecification.loadModelFile(DependencyParserCache.java:53)
  edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParserCache.loadFromModelFile(DependencyParserCache.java:76)
  edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser.loadFromModelFile(DependencyParser.java:498)

If only "rer" is present on params the request return without errors but come without relations infos, i get only entities and tokens and without the key openie on result raising a error on line "for triple in sentence['openie']:"
Any sugestion ?
